# What is an effective way to check Freemarker templates for common errors?

Tags: java, freemarker, lint

We have been running into the problem of template errors occasionally sneaking into our production site. If there were a tool to catch these or a strategy to catch these problems ahead of time then it could be added to the delivery pipeline.

Comment: Would you consider switching to Google Closure Templates? It can compile the templates during build, and it also generate Java constants for each template and model object which you refer to in your code. This way both syntax errors and broken references in code get picked up at compile time.

Comment: Closed, but still a good question IMHO.

I achieved a lint by calling Template.process() with an empty Map as a model and then ignoring all exceptions apart from freemarker.core.ParseException.  This enables me to do some syntax checking in a JUnit test.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, Freemarker really only has two classes of errors when trying to render a template (Ignoring configuration):

- Simple syntax errors at the template level
- Assumptions about the model passed in at the Java level are incorrect

Although linting tools typically do find errors in code, a lint tool does not replace the need for basic testing, which is a far better solution for what you're experiencing here since you are seeing exceptions in production code.

For better or for worse, Freemarker's assumptions about who is working with the data and who is working with the markup are different people with different skillsets.  Assuming this is the case (and you have Java engineering resources to spare), you have two ways of approaching this problem from a test process point of view (Although to be truly rigorous, you want both).

### Frontend Testing

At my previous job, we used this approach by itself.  Basically, the front-end engineers would hack templates on a special web frontend where the edited templates were directly on the configuration path containing two listings:

- The template to render
- Versions of the data model to render

The 'versions' were essentially a two-tiered set of hardcoded Java objects, where Tier 1 was consistent across all of templates, and Tier 2 was template-specific variations.  Because most of our emails were account-level notifications, we got a lot of mileage and reuse out of just having the global data model, and we rarely had to dig into the small stuff.

**Benefits**

- The Frontend engineers never need to touch Java, so you can use your HTML/CSS mavens for their intended purpose if that's what you have on your team
- The Backend engineers can recycle a lot of stuff depending on the templates and their construction
- Loosely enforces a uniformity of data model variable names when referring to frequently used values such as "account" (The Frontend engineers would get annoyed when values they expected weren't there because a different backend engineer named something 'incorrectly')

**Not So Good**

- This basically is manual testing, and at some point will fail to catch an error

### Backend Testing

The other alternative is form unit tests for each template as they are created.  Because the exceptions in Freemarker all happen at compile time, you will only need to do the following (After you do initial setup):

```
Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("myTestedTemplate.ftl");
temp.process(myTestDataModel, myIgnoredOutput); // No exceptions -> OK for us
```

Note that you don't care about the result in this case, you just need it to compile.  This is important because you can easily get bogged down in debugging compiled output in Java and not solve the current problem.  As before, you will also want to do the same two-tiers of unit tests here in all likelihood:

- Smoke test all templates with some generic model (Getting each template can likely be done programmatically)
- Test individual templates with the variations in data model that you expect (Missing settings, incomplete fields, etc.)

**Benefits**

- Part of the build/deploy process, so you eliminate human error in the templates
- Depending on how you are using Freemarker, this can also verify the data models are being generated correctly by other processes if you aren't doing so already

**Not-So-Good**

- Frontend Engineers will need to read stack traces to find out what failed
- Development using this method ends up getting tied to your build process, which is nowhere near as fast as reloading a page

If you have the time to do both, I would recommend work on using unit tests to handle the edge cases and other concerns that you find as they pop up, then the web frontend for development so that developing the page doesn't require a recompile.  The ability to version frontend is extremely beneficial, but the goal is to prevent errors in production to the build process first.  Launch, then optimize and all.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean runtime output errors and not template syntax errors, you could use a (brittle) set of "expect-got" integration tests. How appropriate this is depends on the complexity of your templates and how dynamic they are. If you just want some simple "smoke" tests, this is probably a good solution.

For each template, create at least one test. Using concrete/static/pre-specified input data and concrete/static/pre-specified output results. This output has to be manually generated and verified the first time after any change, but from then on it can be saved and testing can be scripted. If the template pulls in its own data (like dates, etc) that can't be set as fixed input, mask or remove this from the expected output. Each automated test should:

1. Generate "got" output from at least one set of input data for each template.
2. Mask or remove unpredictable variable regions from the output.
3. Compare this "got" result to the saved, pre-verified "expected" output.
4. Report failures when these are not the same.

Exact output equality is the easiest to implement and ensure are correct. If needed, have multiple tests per template. I wouldn't try to be clever, just let the computer do boring and repetative work. I would ignore the parts of the template that need to be masked on a first pass (some testing is better then none). Write explicit tests just for them later when you decide it improves reliability enough to be worth the effort (or for any that have been done  wrong in the past.)

This solutions has the following caveats.

1. The scope is too large. Any change to anything in the template or in the data model can require updating the test. Using "diff" might help with manual verification and determining how to modify tests when data models and/or templates change.
2. Code refuse and modularity causes testing problems. With good, modular code, one code change can affect data in all templates, but static test require changing and reverifying all the tests independently when this happens. Not much to be done to fix that, so the better and more modular your code, the more work this causes :(
3. Sophisticated templates are hard to test. It might be problematic to have good template coverage using only a few sets of static data. That could mean the templates are doing too much "processing" and are not really being used just as template. That is probably not a good idea anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about a tool that does this for you, but to catch the syntactical errors, all you have to do is giving all your template files to `new Template("whatever", theTemplateFileReader);`. Unfortunately, you can't detect runtime errors this way, such as references to non-existant variables/macros/imports. For that you could call `Template.process`, but without the data-model that you will have in the actual application it doesn't make sense of course.

Comment: This will just throw exceptions as soon as it hits a model reference.

Comment: As I said, `new Template` doesn't care about the model, it just checks the syntax. And also as I said, `Template.process` won't work without a concrete data model.